# 2d Portal teleport Issue

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

[image]

Please see the attached image. There are 3 blocks each have a portal on it, portal is child of black, now there is red ball, so the ball will hit the portal and the ball will come out from another two portal, I want a correct position of the ball form the portal that it come out. e.g the when the ball hit the portal then the ball should come out form another portal on the same hit point.

thanks

Comment: Sounds fun. Do you have a question?

Comment: hi thanks,  Yes i want to correctly position the ball when it comes out form another portal.

Comment: no one is stopping you from doing so ;) what have you tried so far and what is going wrong with your approach?

Comment: yes no one is stopping me lolz, basically when the red ball hit the portal   i am doing like this. redball.transform.position =  portal2.transform.position  + new Vector3 ( portal1.transform.position.x - ballhitPoint.x, portal1.transform.position.y - ballhitPoint.y, 0);  the above code is working good  when portal is on vertical (90 degree )  or in horizontal but when the portal is have different angle then the red ball is not positioned properly .  e.g when the ball comes out from portal 3 its not on correct position. i need help in this.thanks

Answer (score 0):

You aren't taking care of rotated portals, that's why it isnt working.

Assuming each portals transform.right is pointing out of the portal, Vector.forward is perpendicular to your 2D plane and the ball is going from portal1 to portal2, you could something like this:
1. Calculate the vector `Vector3 v = ballhitPoint - portal1.transform.position`
2. Determine the directed rotation between portal1 and portal2: `float r = (Mathf.Atan2(portal2.forward.y, portal2.forward.x) - Mathf.Atan2(portal1.forward.y, portal1.forward.x)) * 180 / Mathf.PI`
3. Rotate v by the same amount `vNew = Quaternion.AngleAxis(r, Vector3.forward)`
4. Set the ball position `redball.transform.position = portal2.transform.position + vNew`

In summary what you want to achieve (if I understood your problem correctly): You have a hitpoint on a portal and want to project that hitpoint to a target portal.

I have not tested this code and I also don't know how exactly you are using 3D vectors in your 2D game, so you may have to change some of the calculations to fit your axis. For more info on the functions I have used, I want to refer unitys documentation.